# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol ‘RequestConfiguration’

Tags: android, admob

I am modifying an android app, which used to work, but the test ad is no longer loaded and in the Android Studio log I see:

*Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("8B…D76C") to get test ads on this device.*

I tried to add that to the code, but I get a “Cannot resolve symbol ‘RequestConfiguration’.
Unfortunately Android Studio is not suggesting what's the package which needs to be imported.

This is how the code look after adding the requested line.

```
RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("device_id_3");

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
      // Add a test device to show Test Ads
      .addTestDevice(“device_id_1") 
      .addTestDevice("device_id_2")
      .addTestDevice("device_id_3") 
      .build();

// Load ads into Banner Ads
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 6):

Firebase is not needed, if you check AdMob documentation:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices , you will need to add following code instead of what the suggestion you see in the log cat:

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("<<< copy the device ID from logcat here >>>");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

this must be added to build.gradle:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to run the `.build()` method on the `RequestConfiguration.builder()`

The builder is just a static class that configures and returns a RequestConfiguration object via the `.build()` method. 
I am pretty sure that the colsole is telling you "in the usual roundabout way" that you need an instance of RequestConfiguration.

If it still doesn't work, try assigning it to a property:

```
RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
                                                     .ToBuilder()
                                                     .build ();
```

Good luck. In my exp., adding ads is usually the most irritating part of the Android build process (and in your case, the entire life-cycle! XD )

Comment: I presume that I should also import a proper package at the beginning of the java file. Usually Android Studio suggests what to import, but for RequestConfiguration it doesn't. Should I add anything new to the build.gradle?

Comment: Any time you use a class from the API, you have to import the package. Not doing so is sort of like writing your own class, referring to it (using it) in another class, but then deleting the first class before running the program. When Android comes across any reference to that class, it will have no idea what you're talking about. This was the reason for you original error. You were referring to something (an object in your case) that didn't exist. Anyway, good luck. As for the build configuration, I am not sure.